# Fetch keys with matched pattern

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I have a Spring boot application which is connected to Redis.

I want to perform a redis operation to fetch the keys which matches certain pattern.

I understand this can be achieved in multiple ways

1. Redis Template and Keys command : But its not suitable to be used on large data sets . As it may block the client (not the server) for long time and also exhaust the server memory due to the response buffer size.
2. Redis Template and Scan command : Redis docs recommends to use scan command in comparison to Keys. As it does the scanning iteratively which makes faster smaller operations and better on server resources.
3. Spring Data Redis Repository : Fetch all by creating a hash on the pattern in the Redis Entity.

But i am not sure which will give me overall faster performance to fetch all the matched keys under high load and would be recommended for my scenario.

Best Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

Redis is single-threaded so traversing all keys on a large dataset (a large number of keys) may block the server for a long time (even several seconds). And so it is not advised to run 'Keys' in production at all.

The scan operation is built to run iteratively but you should note that you might get the same key more than once and also there is a chance that some keys will not be returned. Overall your system will run faster with Scan.